# window.history.back illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is it that I can do this:

```
$("button").on('click', function(){window.history.back();});
```

however, when I try;

```
$("button").on('click', window.history.back);
/*or*/ $("button").on('click', history.back);
```

I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
> at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
> at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)

I was under the impression that when there is no retained context it defaults to the window object, which would allow me to do this?

Comment: jQuery expects function as second paramer

Comment: `history.back()` needs to be invoked with `history` as the context, **not** `window`. You'll get the same error if you try to run `window.history.back.call(window)`. Regardless, jQuery will invoke the function with the element as context, so it doesn't even default to `window`

Comment: like @MikaelLennholm says, back is part of history, not window.  so you would need to do  `history.back.bind(history)`

Comment: @MikaelLennholm hmmm interesting - so out of interest, if I was to use pure javascript event binding, then my approach would've worked? Also, can confirm that `history.back.bind(history)` does indeed work.

Comment: @Zze `$('button').on('click', history.back.bind(history) );` does not work, how did you run it please?

Comment: @Zze No, it wouldn't work either because `addEventListener` also sets the element as the context for the handler function.

Comment: `$("#goBackBreadcrumb").on('click', history.back.bind(history));` @KresimirPendic this is the exact line which now works.

Comment: @KresimirPendic  What do you mean `history.back.bind(history)` does not work.?

Comment: @Keith I tested the line that I pasted couple of lines up and it does not work,, it works on your end?

Comment: @KresimirPendic Yes, works fine for me, and the OP.  Maybe your test has some other error.

Comment: I strongly recommend the approach you used in the first example in your question. Sure, you can use `history.back.bind(history)` instead, but there is no advantage to that. Your first example with the anonymous callback function that makes the call to `history.back()` is basically the canonical way to do this. It is much more clear than the `.bind()` version. Why make things more complicated than they need to be? The only improvement I would suggest to the first version is to split it into multiple lines in the usual manner so it's not so crowded.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thanks for the comment, I've taken your advice and reverted it to it's original state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `history.back()` must be invoked with `history` as the context, if it defaults to `window` it will throw the error you describe. The issue here though is that jQuery invokes the handler with the element that has the event listener bound.

Your first line of code works because context is irrelevant to the anonymous function you pass as a handler. The fact that jQuery sets the element as the context doesn't matter since you correctly invoke `history.back()` inside of it.

Answer (score 4):

Your working code calls `history.back()`:

```
... window.history.back(); ...
```

That calls `back()` as a method of the `history` object, which simply means that inside the `back` function, `this` is a reference to `history`.

The non-working code gets a reference to the `back` function:

```
... window.history.back ...
```

and then passes the reference into jQuery's `.on()` method.

jQuery calls the function later in response to a `click` event, and `this` is set at the time of that call. jQuery sets `this` to the DOM element receiving the event.

So when the implementation of the `back()` function references `this` expecting it to be the `history` object, it gets the wrong thing.

In general, when you want an event listener to call a function that you didn't write, you're best off wrapping the call inside a function of your own as you did in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

The `history` attribute of `window` simply references the History interface, and can only be invoked globally.

The failing method uses an element context, which has no `history` attribute.